# How to remove leading zeroes from a column in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a column of store IDs which all have leading zeroes. I.E. 0017 shows rather than 17, 0876 shows rather than 876.
All Store IDs are 4 digits long with these leading zeroes. Is there a way to remove these leading zeroes and therefore leave me with 17 and 876 (as per above).
I imagine this would involve a REGEXP statement but I haven't been able to successfully create one yet.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you could replicate the scenario on a fresh Google Data Studio Report using sample data that would also be proof that it is a reproducible issue! if you could then share that Google Data Studio Report publicly and add a link in the question, it would allow fellow users to test it out. Without a Reproducible Example it would be **difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration, Temporary Outage**...

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field using this formula `REGEXP_REPLACE(Store ID, r'^\D*0*', '')`.

Working example [here](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/7979350e-e3c1-43f7-9b0e-6a72b6498892/page/p_ue8fyd0drc).